# ClickOnce Deployment with local user file

Tags: deployment, clickonce, configuration-files

I'd like to deploy a ClickOnce application, but would like to have a configurable user file to store settings and preferences that does not get overwritten everytime I publish a new version.  Is there to specify that a particular file should get deployed in any installation that doesn't already have one, but not overwrite any previous versions?

The only workaround that I can envision is to store the data in a database, but it's so user-centric that it seems like a lot of overhead to re-invent the config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use [application settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4s6c3a0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), which we used for a WPF application deployed with ClickOnce.  We have multiple settings for such things as user specified download folders, default settings, etc.  For each such setting, the *Scope* is set to User.  When the setting is changed by the user the new values are persisted with a call such as:

```
YourProject.Properties.Settings.Default.UserSetting1 = "New Value";
YourProject.Properties.Settings.Default.Save(); // persists the new value for the current user
```

Even with multiple updates of the application via ClickOnce, these settings are persisted for each user.  Note that the settings are persisted on a per-machine basis, so if a user goes to a new machine and downloads the application, their settings will not be transferred.

Hope this helps,